Getting Errors while trying to use clang module with clang-15 and llvm-15
I want to use the pybind11_mkdocs / clang module on my ubuntu 22.04 but can't seem to get past this error ->
undefined symbol: clang_CXXMethod_isDeleted. Did you mean: 'clang_CXXMethod_isDefaulted'

I have tried a hundred approaches on this problem but keep getting stuck on this part of the code.
Basically I have installed clang and llvm version 15.0.7 on my Ubuntu 22.04 and want to run this code ->
import clang

import clang.cindex

clang.cindex.Config.set_library_file('/usr/lib/llvm-15/libclang-15.so.1')

id = clang.cindex.Index.create()

I tried installing llvm and clang versions 5.0.1 following this post -> clang.cindex.LibclangError "Undefined symbol clang_CXXRecord_isAbstract" but couldn't get ahead this same error. Btw here is the complete error I am facing ->
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/clang/cindex.py", line 3832, in register_function
func = getattr(lib, item\[0\])
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/ctypes/__init__.py", line 387, in __getattr__
func = self.__getitem__(name)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/ctypes/__init__.py", line 392, in __getitem__
func = self.\_FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: /usr/lib/llvm-15/lib/libclang.so.1: undefined symbol: clang_CXXMethod_isDeleted. Did you mean: 'clang_CXXMethod_isDefaulted'?


Ok I got ahead of the error by installing the python module specific to my clang version. Since I had clang-15 and llvm-15 installed, I had to pip install clang==15.0.7 which can be found here -> https://pypi.org/project/clang/#history.
